# Generate automatic id from two tables union

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables: composed activities and simple activities:

**composed_activities**

```
id | name    
1  | Activity 1    
5  | Activity 2
```

**simple_activities**

```
id | name    
1  | S Activity 1    
2  | S Activity 2    
3  | S Activity 3
```

I need a query that returns a new generated id, the composed activities with '+' prefix and the simple ones with '-' prefix:

```
id | name

1  | + Activity 1    
2  | + Activity 5    
3  | - S Activity 1    
4  | - S Activity 2    
5  | - S Activity 3
```

So far I have only managed to join both tables but does not generate an id automatically:

```
SELECT id, CONCAT('- ',name) as name 
FROM simple_activities 
UNION 
SELECT id,CONCAT('+ ',name) AS name 
FROM composed_activities
```

Could someone tell me how to generate the id? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Select name, row_number() over (order by name ) as id

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap you union up into a subquery, then use the `ROW_NUMBER()` window function to generate your id:

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY name ASC) as newid, 
    id as oldid, 
    name
FROM 
    (SELECT 
        id, 
        CONCAT('- ',name) as name 
     FROM simple_activities 
     UNION 
     SELECT 
        id,
        CONCAT('+ ',name) AS name 
     FROM composed_activities) subquery
```

Answer (score 1):

JNevill is correct and is the right answer, in less code.

I'm posting using a CTE as I find them easier to read:

```
DECLARE @composed_activities TABLE (id int, name varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @composed_activities (id, name)
VALUES (1,'Activity 1'), (5,'Activity 2')

DECLARE @simple_activities TABLE (id int, name varchar(20))
INSERT INTO @simple_activities (id, name)
VALUES (1,'S Activity 1'), (2,' S Activity 2'), (3,' S Activity 3')

;WITH X (id, name) AS 
(
    SELECT id,'+ '+name FROM @composed_activities
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,'- '+name FROM @simple_activities
), Y AS
    (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY name,id) AS id, name
        FROM X
    )

SELECT * 
FROM Y
```

Comment: I tried this code and it worked too. Thanks for the reply!